# Number of recursion calls for each Fibonacci number

Tags: c++, recursion, counter

**Why is there a variation between the numbers in the output of my code, versus the expected output result (as pasted at the end)?**

I went through these questions related to the calculation of the number of recursive calls:

- [Number of calls for nth Fibonacci number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738923/number-of-calls-for-nth-fibonacci-number)
- [Count number of recursive calls in fibonacci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237930/count-number-of-recursive-calls-in-fibonacci)

I could not form a proper answer or a solution to my question.

I even tried re-initializing the count by writting `call_count = 0;` in the main() function after the for loop or also in the function definitions (as suggested in the answers of the second link above) but, it did not work or give me the expected output.

I have pasted my code below and its output below the code, and the expected output below my code output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int call_count = 0;

int fibo(int n)
{
    call_count+=1;
    if(n<=2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
            //call_count += 1;
            return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
         }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout<<"\nenter the number of integers to be printed in the fibonacci series\n";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"\nfibonacci series for first "<<num<<" numbers is\n";
    cout<<"\n\nSerial Number\t"<<"FIBO_NUMBER\t"<<" NO_OF_CALLS MADE\n\n";
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        cout<<endl<<i<<"th number\t   "<<fibo(i)<<"\t\t"<<call_count<<" calls\n";
    }
cout<<endl<<"\n the total number of recursive calls made were "<<call_count<<endl<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

**The Output for My Code:**

```
enter the number of integers to be printed in the fibonacci series
15

fibonacci series for first 15 numbers is

Serial Number   FIBO_NUMBER      NO_OF_CALLS MADE


1th number         1            0 calls

2th number         1            1 calls

3th number         2            2 calls

4th number         3            5 calls

5th number         5            10 calls

6th number         8            19 calls

7th number         13           34 calls

8th number         21           59 calls

9th number         34           100 calls

10th number        55           167 calls

11th number        89           276 calls

12th number        144          453 calls

13th number        233          740 calls

14th number        377          1205 calls

15th number        610          1958 calls


 the total number of recursive calls made were 3177

Press any key to continue . . .
```

**Whereas the EXPECTED output numbers are as follows:**

```
1 th integer of fibonacci series is 1 and it needed 0 recursive calls
2 th integer of fibonacci series is 1 and it needed 0 recursive calls
3 th integer of fibonacci series is 2 and it needed 2 recursive calls
4 th integer of fibonacci series is 3 and it needed 4 recursive calls
5 th integer of fibonacci series is 5 and it needed 8 recursive calls
6 th integer of fibonacci series is 8 and it needed 14 recursive calls
7 th integer of fibonacci series is 13 and it needed 24 recursive calls
8 th integer of fibonacci series is 21 and it needed 40 recursive calls
9 th integer of fibonacci series is 34 and it needed 66 recursive calls
10 th integer of fibonacci series is 55 and it needed 108 recursive calls
11 th integer of fibonacci series is 89 and it needed 176 recursive calls
12 th integer of fibonacci series is 144 and it needed 286 recursive calls
13 th integer of fibonacci series is 233 and it needed 464 recursive calls
14 th integer of fibonacci series is 377 and it needed 752 recursive calls
15 th integer of fibonacci series is 610 and it needed 1218 recursive calls
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How do I resolve this mismatch?

Comment: Have you tried the debugger yet?

Comment: You are not resetting `call_count` to zero on each loop iteration.

Comment: Also, you need to print `call_count` on a separate statement from the call to `fibo` since it could be evaluated at the call point. And you need to subtract 1 for the initial call!

Comment: @rlbond i have not reset it in the code i pasted but i tried it as described in the details, it gave me wrong call_counts....either zero or the calls reduced to less than half the values as opposed to the present

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN yes i tried a bit, but i am not sure if i am using the debugger correctly or not using dev cpp as i am very new to c++. learner here.

Comment: By resetting `call_count` and subtracting 1, it matches exactly... http://ideone.com/8EWjOC

Comment: @rlbond i tried doing call_count as a seperate statement for printing call count but it still did not match, i am trying the subtraction now

Comment: @CodeMan Dev Cpp is outdated and its debugger was broken the last time I used it. If you are looking for a free IDE, might I recommend Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs it is completely free and up-to-date with C++14.

Comment: @Casey well thanks casey for the ups. i will try in visual studio too.....but even codeblocks is behaving same way

Comment: @rlbond I got it now, there was a small extra syntax that was misbehaving......but now it works Your suggestion. i wrote cout in a seperate statement and reset it to add a negative 1 and it works perfect HUGE THANX TO rlbond!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset the call_count to zero before making call to fibo() method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int call_count = 0;

int fibo(int n)
{
    call_count+=1;
    if(n<=2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
            //call_count += 1;
            return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
         }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout<<"\nenter the number of integers to be printed in the fibonacci series\n";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"\nfibonacci series for first "<<num<<" numbers is\n";
    cout<<"\n\nSerial Number\t"<<"FIBO_NUMBER\t"<<" NO_OF_CALLS MADE\n\n";
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        call_count = 0; 
        cout<<endl<<i<<"th number\t   "<<fibo(i)<<"\t\t"<<call_count<<" calls\n";
    }
    cout<<endl<<"\n the total number of recursive calls made were "    <<call_count<<endl<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok am trying this right away and will be back with what the result is thanks.

Comment: You need to split the stream operator for `call_count` to another line.

Comment: So Nope it did not work, when i tried your code , the function calls went down to zero for each call..... all the calls are zero6th number         8            0 calls
<br/>
7th number         13           0 calls

8th number         21           0 calls

9th number         34           0 calls

10th number        55           0 calls

11th number        89           0 calls

12th number        144          0 calls

13th number        233          0 calls

14th number        377          0 calls

15th number        610          0 calls

 the total number of recursive calls made were 1219

Comment: the total number somehow matches now but the individual call print statement not yeilding right results

Comment: @rlbond your earlier suggestion worked perfectly, it was just some random extra syntax character that was misbehaving with the code output. thanks. a lot will answer my own question in an hour, i got some meeting rt now

Answer (score 0):

Collectively summarizing from the pin-point inputs of @rlbond and @zeroCool, along with a tiny change to both to form a single answer:-

resetting call_count to zero on each loop iteration, and printing the call_count on a separate statement from the call to fibo (since it could be evaluated at the call point), will yield the expected output. 
Also one needs to subtract 1 from call_count (for the initial call), while printing out the count statement for each fibonacci number to get the expected count.

Following Code reduces the need of an extra variable and splits the print statement evaluating to expected output. (alternatively one could refer to the link from rlbond's comment on the question above. [ideone.com/8EWjOC](http://ideone.com/8EWjOC) )

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int call_count = 0;

int fibo(int n)
{
    call_count+=1;
    if(n<=2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
            return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
         }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout<<"\nenter the number of integers to be printed in the fibonacci series\n";
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"\nfibonacci series for first "<<num<<" numbers is\n";
    cout<<"\n\nSerial Number\t"<<"FIBO_NUMBER\t"<<" NO_OF_CALLS MADE\n\n";
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
        call_count = 0;
        cout<<endl<<i<<"th number\t   "<<fibo(i)<<"\t\t";
        cout<<call_count-1<<" calls\n";
    }
cout<<endl<<"\n the total number of recursive calls made were "<<call_count-1<<endl<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

**Works fine, output as follows:-**

enter the number of integers to be printed in the fibonacci series
15

fibonacci series for first 15 numbers is

Serial Number   FIBO_NUMBER      NO_OF_CALLS MADE

1th number         1            0 calls

2th number         1            0 calls

3th number         2            2 calls

4th number         3            4 calls

5th number         5            8 calls

6th number         8            14 calls

7th number         13           24 calls

8th number         21           40 calls

9th number         34           66 calls

10th number        55           108 calls

11th number        89           176 calls

12th number        144          286 calls

13th number        233          464 calls

14th number        377          752 calls

15th number        610          1218 calls

the total number of recursive calls made were 1218

Press any key to continue . . .

gratitude to everyone's contribution.